# Double Character problem i.e. make a code that prints out "TThhee" if the input string is "The" in python 3

Tags: python

I had a go at this problem and got

```
def doub_char(string):
    for i in string:
        string2 = print(2*i)
    return string2
    
doub_char("Money")
```

but this printed:

```
MM
oo
nn
ee
yy
```

instead of

```
"MMoonneeyy"
```

Comment: Use three backwards apostrophes ("backtick") for code formatting, not the normal apostrophes.

Comment: Use `print(2*i, end='')` to avoid the newline.

Comment: you need to declare/define string2 before for loop and add these character to the string 2